# Finding the median of a list of even numbers

Tags: python, list, statistics

I'm doing a coding challenge where I need to find the min, max, average and median of a list and output two tuples (one of them being squared).

I've managed to output the correct results apart from the median of a list that has odd numbers (e.g. ([7,2,4,5]) should return [(2, 4.5, 4.5, 7), (4, 23.5, 20.5, 49)].

Instead, I get ((2, 4.5, 3.0, 7), (4, 23.5, 10.0, 49)). It would also be helpful if anyone knew how to round the numbers.

```
def exercise3(l):
    l2 = [number ** 2 for number in l]    
    def median(l):
        l.copy().sort()
        if len(l)%2 != 0:
            median = l[len(l)//2]
            return median
        elif len(l)%2 == 0:
            mid = (len(l)//2)-1
            median = (l[mid] + l[mid+1]) / 2
            return median
    def calcStats(l):
        minL = min(l)
        avgL = sum(l) / len(l)
        medL = median(l)
        maxL = max(l)
        return minL, avgL, medL, maxL
    
    return calcStats(l), calcStats(l2)
```

Comment: Thanks but as part of the challenge we can't use libraries

Answer (score 1):

If usage of python standard library is not prohibited by the rules of your contest I would go with

```
from statistics import median
median(l)
```